# How can should I set up Flex 3 projects that reference common controls?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, mxml

I'm not a flash developer, I'm having issues figuring out how I should set up these two projects that I have in Flex Builder.

I've already created projA which has a .mxml that references several custom controls & skins from com.xxx.controls within projA

I now have to build projB which also has a .mxml that will create a different .swf.  I want to use some of the same controls from projA

I currently build projA through the command line and nant and will need to do the same for projB.

Should I create a new project to move all of the common controls into?  How do I then use this library project in both the projects & compile via command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the best way to handle this is to create a separate (swc) library project and reference that in both projects.

You can set the references to the libraries in the build path settings of both projects in Flex/Flash Builder and via the include-libraries compiler option in ant.

Comment: Can you provide some tutorials that show how to set this up?  I'm very inexperienced with Flex and have a hard time navigating the UI.  I'm most concerned about breaking projA which is already complete.  Will I have to change how I reference the controls in projA?  Thanks :)